# Выдает большую ошибку от бота телеграмм на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types 
import random


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti=open('stikers/hello_game.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    #keyboard
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1=types.KeyboardButton("random cifra")
    item2=types.KeyboardButton("how are you?")

    markup.add(item1,item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"privetstvou tebya, {0.first_name}!\nYa - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, stupid bot ot tovarischa Fletla".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html',reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lolomg(message):
    if message.chat.type=='private':
        if message.text=='random cifra':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
        elif message.text=='how are you?':
            markup=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup("horosho",callback_data='good')
            item2=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup("ploho",callback_data='bad')

            markup.add(item1,item2)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'namana, sam kak?',perly_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ya ne znau kak tebe otvetit')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data=='good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'vot i horosho')
            elif call.data=='bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'bivaet')
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ты нажал?")
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Писал бота для телеграмм по гайду(написан код как в гайде) и мне выдает огромную ошибку где python ругается на много чего(где я ошибок не ввижу). Ошибка находится в ссылке ниже:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjrec.png

изменено: в одной строке написал не reply_markup, а perly_markup.
и еще не InlineKeyboardButton, а InlineKeyboardMarkup(сам когда начал искать рядом с callback_data нашел эти ошибки)

Comment: Понятная ошибка, ругается на этой строке `item1=types.InlineKeyboardMarkup("horosho",callback_data='good')`... Означает что вы не можете передавать значение *good* для *callback_data*, потому что такого аргумента нет

Comment: У [`InlineKeyboardMarkup`](https://core.telegram.org./bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup) нет параметра `callback_data`.